# Sequelize get MySql stored procedure data as array?

Tags: mysql, json, stored-procedures, sequelize.js

If I call a stored procedure in sequelize, like so:

```
var query = "CALL GetSatellites();"
sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
         .spread(responseWithResult(res))
         .catch(handleError(res));
```

and .json() convert it, I get:

```
{
  "0": {
    "timestamp": "2018-02-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "severity": "critical",
    "device": "battery",
    "identifier": "P2",
    "name": "P2 Battery Recover",
    "detail": ""
  },
  "1": {
    "timestamp": "2018-02-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "severity": "critical",
    "device": "battery",
    "identifier": "P3",
    "name": "P3 Battery Recover",
    "detail": ""
  }
}
```

but I'd really like it to do the more common output you get when you make a very similar SELECT query:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM Satellites;"
sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
         .then(responseWithResult(res))
         .catch(handleError(res));
```

which, when .json()'d, I get:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "SatelliteId": 1,
    "createdAt": "2018-02-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-02-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    "satelliteUTCTime": "2018-02-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    "identifier": "P1",
    "name": "P1 Battery Recover",
    "severity": "critical",
    "device": "battery",
    "detail": "Kablooee!"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "SatelliteId": 1,
    "createdAt": "2018-02-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-02-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "satelliteUTCTime": "2018-02-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "identifier": "P2",
    "name": "P2 Battery Recover",
    "severity": "critical",
    "device": "battery",
    "detail": ""
  }
]
```

I'm already using spread() to get past the metadata returned by the stored procedure, but is there some setting or call in sequelize I can use to get a clean array of objects from a stored procedure call like I do with a direct SELECT?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set an OUT parameter in your SP.

here's a demo code:

```js
sequelize.query('SET @outputData = null; CALL stored_procedure (:someInputData, @outputData); SELECT @outputData;',
    {
      replacements: {
        someInputData: 'Send Your Data Here',
      },
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW,
    })
    .spread(response => console.log(response, 'response'))
    .error((error) => {
      console.log(error, 'errored');
    });
```

Note: add 'multipleStatements: true' to your sequelize config while creating instance, like so:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database.dbName, config.database.username, config.database.password,
  {
    host: config.database.host,
    dialect: config.database.dialect,
    logging: false,
    dialectOptions: {
      multipleStatements: true,
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use type: `sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW` and `.then` instead of `.spread`.
That worked for me. May be the reason is that Model is not set for procedure calls.